how to position elements in the many layers of this tier circle, distributed evenly and equidistant from the center?
Image of the css concentric circles i have
I need to display items dinamically given a list of jsons, but what i need to know is how to get all the items in the correct position. I thought of doing something like
tier A (inner circle) = 20px from center, tier B (second circle from center) = 120px from center and so on
and position the items with the pair (distanceFromCenter, angle) with angle starting at top being 0.
Is there a way to do this? or do it in a easyer way?
import React from 'react'
import styles from './test.module.css'

export default function RadarComponent() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
        <h1>Radar Cadmus</h1>
        <div className={styles.circleOne}>
            <div className={styles.circleTwo}>
                <div className={styles.circleThree}>
                    <div className={styles.circleFour}>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.circleOne{
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50% ;
    background-color: green;
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.circleTwo{
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50% ;
    background-color: rgb(128, 255, 0);
    width: 550px;
    height: 550px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.circleThree{
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50% ;
    background-color: rgb(242, 255, 0);
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.circleFour{
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50% ;
    background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

I tried using chartJs radar but the problem is i can't make the sections different colors and one added item in the dataset changes the whole position of all items, because the radar chart has relative positions.
'use client';

import React from 'react';
import { Radar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  RadialLinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Filler,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';

ChartJS.register(
  RadialLinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Filler,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
);


const data = {
  labels: ['Eating', 'Drinking', 'Sleeping', 'Designing', 'Coding', 'Cycling', 'Running'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First Dataset',
    data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    fill: false, // Não preencher o fundo
    borderColor: 'transparent', // Tornar a linha invisível
    pointBackgroundColor: '#415364', // Cor das bolinhas
    pointBorderColor: '#415364',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#415364',
    pointHoverBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointRadius: 5, // Tamanho das bolinhas
  }]
};

const options = {
  elements: {
    line: {
      borderWidth: 3,
    },
  },
  scales: {
    r: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0 , 1)',
      angleLines: {
        display: false, //if true shows angleLines that cross with the ticks
      },
      grid: {
        circular: true, //this allows the ticks to be circular and not polygonal
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
      },
      ticks: { //a tick is one of the circunferences of the chart
        color: 'black',
        count: 5, //number of ticks
        display: false, //if true show tick labels
      },
      pointLabels: {
        font: {
          size: 12,
          weight: 'bold',
        },
        color: 'black',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  },
};

// Função para obter o texto do marcador
const getMarkerText = (value: number) => {
  if (value >= 75) return 'Alto';
  if (value >= 50) return 'Médio';
  return 'Baixo';
};

export default function RadarComponent() {
    
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '600px', height: '600px' }}>
      <Radar options={options} data={data}/>
    </div>
  );
}


enter image description here

Is there any reason the the circles need to be separate elements?

I'd suggest a rather simpler method - position each blob as the background within a slim element which has height of the circle's radius and rotate the element according to its child position (0 to 6).
This snippet also puts the labels in place by positioning them in an element within each rotated element - and rotated back again to make them all horizontal.
Note: this snippet also draws the background circles as a CSS background but if you do need them to be 4 separate elements then use your original code.


<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .chart {
    background-image: radial-gradient(rgb(255, 153, 0) 0 17.5%, rgb(242, 255, 0) 17.5% 35%, rgb(128, 255, 0) 35% 52.5%, green 52.5% 70%, transparent 70% 100%);
    --r: 40vmin;
    width: calc(2 * var(--r));
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .datum {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 10vmin;
    height: var(--r);
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(calc(1deg * var(--n) * 360 / var(--num)));
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    background-image: radial-gradient(gray 0 70%, transparent 70% 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center calc(var(--r) - ((var(--data) * var(--r)) / 100));
    background-size: 2vmin 2vmin;
  }
  
  .blob {
    transform: rotate(calc(-1deg * var(--n) * 360 / var(--num)));
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2em;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="chart"></div>
</body>
<script>
  const labels = ['Eating', 'Drinking', 'Sleeping', 'Designing', 'Coding', 'Cycling', 'Running'];
  const data = [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40];
  const num = labels.length;
  const chart = document.querySelector('.chart');
  chart.style.setProperty('--num', num);
  for (let n = 0; n < num; n++) {
    const datum = document.createElement('div');
    datum.classList.add('datum');
    datum.style.setProperty('--n', n);
    datum.style.setProperty('--data', data[n]);
    const blob = document.createElement('div');
    blob.innerHTML = labels[n];
    blob.classList.add('blob');
    datum.appendChild(blob);
    chart.appendChild(datum);
  }
</script>



